# Delaying a CABasicAnimation instantly draws it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cabasicanimation

Im trying to animate a pair of lines that split multiple times. They will have a variable number of splits but I'm trying to make the next split begin only after the previous one has completed. All a split is is a small gap between the end of a segment of a line and the start of the next segment. Also I will eventually have each segment take a specific amount of time to complete but I can't get the animations to delay so I can link them together.

Im using [Advanced Animation Tricks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html) as reference but whenever I open the view controller, which calls the function this animation is stored in, all of the line segments are instantly drawn with no animation or delay and I have no idea why this is happening.

Heres my animation process:

```
for i in 0...(splits.count - 1)
{
    //create path
    //start buffered after split
    //finish buffered before split
    let path1 = UIBezierPath()
    path1.move(to: CGPoint(x: lineSplits[i] + 5, y: lineLoc[0] - CGFloat(lw/2)))
    path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: lineSplits[i] + 5, y: lineLoc[0] - CGFloat(lw/2)))
    path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: lineSplits[i + 1] - 5, y: lineLoc[0] - CGFloat(lw/2)))

    let path2 = UIBezierPath()
    path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: lineSplits[i] + 5, y: lineLoc[0] + CGFloat(lw/2)))
    path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: lineSplits[i] + 5, y: lineLoc[0] + CGFloat(lw/2)))
    path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: lineSplits[i + 1] - 5, y: lineLoc[0] + CGFloat(lw/2)))

    // create shape layer for that path
    let shapeLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer1.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
    shapeLayer1.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1).cgColor
    shapeLayer1.lineWidth = CGFloat(lw)
    shapeLayer1.path = path1.cgPath

    let shapeLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer2.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
    shapeLayer2.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1).cgColor
    shapeLayer2.lineWidth = CGFloat(lw)
    shapeLayer2.path = path2.cgPath

    // animate it with a delay
    let currentLayerTime1 = shapeLayer1.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    let currentLayerTime2 = shapeLayer2.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer1)
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.beginTime = currentLayerTime1 + 5
    animation.duration = 5
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.backwards
    shapeLayer1.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")


    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
    let animation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    //animation2.fromValue = 0
    animation2.beginTime = currentLayerTime2 + 10
    animation2.duration = 10
    animation2.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.backwards
    shapeLayer2.add(animation2, forKey: "MyAnimation")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to substitute the `antimation.beginTime` with:

```
animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 5
```

Instead of the `currentLayerTime1` that you're using.

Comment: Same issue unfortunately, no change at all

Comment: I fixed it! I added the line:

`animation.fromValue = 0`

To each and that solved it, I swore I tried that before to no avail, thanks for the help!